# how to create custom Directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

i was trying  a sample pagination for that i have created an directive like this(am not sure its correct)

```
(function() {
app.directive("myPagination", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'pag.html'
    };
 });
})();
```

and  my `pag.html` is

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-controller="PagingController">
<li ng-repeat="x  in pageing" ng-click="change(x.pageno)"><a href="#">{{x.pageno}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my `PageingController` is like this

```
 app.controller('PagingController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('pageinfo', function(event, args) {
        $scope.numbtn = args.numbtn;
        $scope.totaldata = args.totaldata;
        $scope.selet = args.selet;
        $scope.starter();
    })

    $scope.starter = function() {
        $scope.pageing = [];
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.numbtn; i++) {
            $scope.pageing[i] = i;
        }
        console.log($scope.pageing);
    }
    $scope.change = function(btnclk) {
        alert(btnclk);
    }
});
```

and `<my-pagination></my-pagination>` this is how i tried in index page. but the problem is its not showing anything even no errors can any one correct this please

Comment: mmm just double check the path of your templateUrl of directive ... it has to be from the root of your project

Comment: You shouldn't have `ng-controller` in template for `directive`.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). See also [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `PageingController` controller to directive instead of the template

```
(function() {
app.directive("myPagination", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'pag.html',
        controller : 'PagingController'
    };
 });
})()
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M6eEiTU1XtuBAAg2xqEZ?p=preview)

Make sure subscriber event `$on` is executing. otherwise page array is empty

Comment: i tried this but getting `Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument

Argument 'PageingController' is not a function, got undefined

` error

Comment: spelling mistake should be `PagingController`

Comment: now its not getting error...but `<my-pagination></my-pagination>` is not displaying..am i wrong anywhere else..?

Comment: try to remove `on` function and add this `$scope.pageing = [{pageno : 1},{pageno : 2}]` array. Check and tell me is it working

Comment: i alredy updated it like this ` $scope.pageing=[];` `$scope.pageing.push({pageno :i});`but no result

Comment: can u create a plnkr